# Suggestion : Java server implementation for web application

Tags: java, web-applications

I know this question might be repeated many times but would really appreciate any suggestions. I am working on developing a web application in java (server side). The client is developed in javascript and html5 (another guy) and i want to make the developement independent. I have been using java for quite long  but have no experience in web development. After endlessly going thorugh many forums and articles i am so confused. 
The web app is pretty simple one with options for user to login and upload some data and access those later.
I started with basic sevlets and JDBC APIs. The web application is not very complex one

Currently i have servlets for each resource to handle post and get call on them.

The suggestion i am looking for is do i need to use some framework to make it better. There are so many like springs, playframework, wicket etc.

Any link to sample web applications developed just usin servlets apis will also do a great deal to me

Thanks in advance for the suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need any framework.  As you said your app was pretty simple one. A java Framework could make a complex app organized. But would make a simple app complex.

However, if in the future, you want to extend your app further more. you might need a framework. The most famous web frameworks in java are SSH(spring, struts, hibernate), you can find a lot of materials easily, so I won't dive into the detail here. SSH frameworks are not easy, avoid using them if you app is not complex enough.